# Jump to Reset Vector

Tags: c, embedded

I am trying to jump back to the reset vector and re run my program from main. This is my code but it does not work. Is there anything wrong with this?

```
 typedef void (*reset_vector_jump)(void); 
 ((reset_vector_jump)RESET_VECTOR_ADDRESS)();
```

Comment: What is your target CPU/MCU, exactly?

Comment: @Andrejs Cainikovs the target cpu is quark

Comment: I don't see how this makes any sense. Why would there ever be any reason why you don't want the hardware to reset, but just the software? Usually resetting both at once is an excellent idea, as it will revert all hardware and internal registers in the MCU to default settings. So don't jump anywhere, simply reset the MCU.

Comment: @ Lundin Its a test I'm running its not for any functional reason

Comment: @Lundin This approach is done sometimes to start the application from bootloader after firmware update. Hardware reset starts the bootloader.

Comment: @Andrejs Cainikovs Is the method I used correct though. That should jump to address

Comment: The processor in use (and the board if it is COTS) is relevant to the question, and should be added to the question not placed in a comment.  Generally you should respond to questions about the question by improving the question, not replying in a comment.  You should also normally ask a question about what you actually need to achieve rather than about some method you have decided will achieve it.  This looks like an [XY](http://xyproblem.info/) problem to me.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs : Yes, but in that case the processor state is as expected by the application.  Here he is jumping to the reset vector, not the application start.

Comment: "does not work" in what way?  Does not compile, crashes, seg-faults, does nothing!?

Comment: for intel shouldn't it be at linear address of `0xFFFFFFF0`? Wonder what would happen if you just jumped to that address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All those comments are relevant however if you absolutely need to jump to reset handler from anywhere which you need to sometimes, particularly when you're doing bootloader and reprogramming, this is how you do it, you are very close.

In my case the target Micro is Kinetis ARM cortex4 and my reset vector is hardcoded at location 0x00000004. See below:

```
/* Interrupt vector table */
__attribute__ ((section (".vectortable"))) const tVectorTable __vect_table = {
    /* ISR name                    No.   Address    Pri Name                          Description */
    &__SP_INIT,                 /* 0x00  0x00000000 -   ivINT_Initial_Stack_Pointer   used by PE */
    (tIsrFunc)&__thumb_startup, /* 0x01  0x00000004 -   ivINT_Initial_Program_Counter used by PE */ 
};
```

Therefore location 0x00000004 contains the address of the reset handler i.e. `&__thumb_startup`. So this is what I did:

```
typedef void (*reset_vector_jump)(void); //exactly as you've done  
#define RESET_VECTOR_ADDRESS ((uint32_t *) 0x00000004) // a pointer to uint32_t

((reset_vector_jump)*RESET_VECTOR_ADDRESS)();//CALL IT
```

That works for me. So basically you were missing one additional level of dereferencing.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't understand when you ask a question here on SO you have to justify yourself before people respond with an answer. I explained that this was a for a test. Yes I know this should not be used in normal behavior. But when you are testing something surely that is ok. Once again thanks for your answer it worked perfect for me.

Comment: Actually you need to do it under certain scenarios. Specifically during reprogramming, you need to jump back and forth between Application code and the Boot loader code however if a mechanism is available for a hard reset ,that would be safer.

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to run code intended to run from the reset state while in a processor state that is not the reset state.  In all but the simplest of processors this is likely to fail.  If the code up-to the point you make this jump has has done anything such as configuring a memory management unit, enabling interrupts, initiating a watchdog timer, or configuring a PLL, the reset code will be running in an environment that it does not expect.

You should at the very least disable interrupts.  You might just get away with it then, but it depends on the complexity of the processor and what hardware or peripherals may have been enabled and are active.  Specifically if the MMU has been enabled the reset vector may no longer be a valid address.

One problem specific to x86 processors is that for backward compatibility they startup in 16 bit *real mode*.  If when you attempt the jump, the processor is in *protected mode*, the code at the reset vector will be meaningless.  Switching back to real mode necessarily requires a processor reset in any case.

A safer approach is to force a true reset.  If the processor has a watchdog timer, enabling it but not servicing it is one way of doing that.  Some architectures have a soft reset instruction, while others have a reset controller peripheral that can do that directly.  Your board may have a GPIO connection to the reset pin to allow this.

Comment: Very complete answer.

Comment: Good answer, I'd add that many (most) CPU/MCU can also detect the type of reset at startup (POR, WDR...)  that can be useful to change stuff of startup behavior.